# How to rotate a sidebar nav menu as in the model?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I'll explain what I'm looking for. At the moment, I created the entire layout with a CSS grid, I just missed the sidenavbar (example on the first link), but I don't know how to make a list fit in the grid, once I transform: rotate my element it goes away from the screen.

This is the model:

[image: This is the model]

This is where I stand at the moment.

[image: This is where I stand at the moment]

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans:wght@100&display=swap');

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: medium;
    font-family: noto;
}

:root {
        /* colors */
    --colNoirPhoto: #181818;
    --col1: #2F4858;
    --col2: #165B6F;
    --col3: #00707E;
    --col4: #008483;
    --col5: #00987D;
    --col6: #04AA6D;
    --alt1: #0BE0BA;
    --alt2: #00BFC9;
    --alt3: #ffffff;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
}
    /*side nav bar*/
.sidebar {
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
    color: var(--alt3);
}
    /* top content--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.topcontainer {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    background-color: var(--colNoirPhoto);
    margin-top: 7%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20vh;
    padding-left: 2vh;
}

.titretopcontainer {
    color: var(--alt3);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}

.tiretopcontainer h1 {
    font-size: 18px;
}

.topcontainer img {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    width: 88%;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-column-start: 2;
}
    /* fin detop content--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    
    
    /* biographie content--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.containerAllContent {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 10% 90%;
    background-image: url(/background\ page\ content.png);
}

.separateurdechapitre1 {
    display: flex;
    padding-left: 1vh;
    padding-right: 1vh;
    padding-top: 1vh;
    background-color: var(--col1);
    height: 5vh;
    color: var(--alt3);
    grid-column-start: 2;
}

.separateurdechapitre2 {
    display: flex;
    padding-left: 1vh;
    padding-right: 1vh;
    padding-top: 1vh;
    background-color: var(--col2);
    height: 5vh;
    color: var(--alt3);
    grid-column-start: 2;
}

.separateurdechapitre3 {
    display: flex;
    padding-left: 1vh;
    padding-right: 1vh;
    padding-top: 1vh;
    background-color: var(--col3);
    height: 5vh;
    color: var(--alt3);
    grid-column-start: 2;
}

.separateurdechapitre4 {
    display: flex;
    padding-left: 1vh;
    padding-right: 1vh;
    padding-top: 1vh;
    background-color: var(--col4);
    height: 5vh;
    color: var(--alt3);
    grid-column-start: 2;
}

.content {
    padding-left: 2vh;
    padding-right: 2vh;
    padding-top: 2vh;
    padding-bottom: 2vh;
    grid-column-start: 2;
}
    /* fin de biographie content--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
p {
    color: black;
}

footer {
    background-color: var(--col1);
}
```

```html
<main>   
  <div class="topcontainer">
    <div class="titretopcontainer">
      <h1>John Conway
      </h1>
      <h2> Créateur du jeu de la vie
      </h2>  
    </div>
    <img src="/Photo de John Conway.png" alt="Photo de John Conway">
  </div>
  <div class="containerAllContent">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <a href="">Biographie
      </a>
      <a href="">Réalisations
      </a>
      <a href="">Distinctions
      </a>     
      <a href="">Voir aussi
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="separateurdechapitre1">
      <h6>En quelques lignes
      </h6>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        Architecto laudantium, temporibus nemo possimus inventore
        soluta amet exercitationem cumque nobis quasi?
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="separateurdechapitre2">
      <h6>En quelques lignes
      </h6>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        Architecto laudantium, temporibus nemo possimus inventore
        soluta amet exercitationem cumque nobis quasi?
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="separateurdechapitre3">
      <h6>En quelques lignes
      </h6>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        Architecto laudantium, temporibus nemo possimus inventore
        soluta amet exercitationem cumque nobis quasi?
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="separateurdechapitre4">
      <h6>En quelques lignes
      </h6>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        Architecto laudantium, temporibus nemo possimus inventore
        soluta amet exercitationem cumque nobis quasi?
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>    
</main>
<footer>
  <p>-
  </p>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Reading your question, I did not fully understand:**

1. If you want your sidebar menu to be aligned vertically instead of horizontally as before.
2. Or whether you want the menu text to be laid out vertically.

**Solution for 1.:**

This can be done by setting the CSS property's [`flex-direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction) value to `column` for the element `<div class="sidebar">`.

**CSS**

```
.sidebar {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: fixed;
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
    color: var(--alt3);
}
```

**Solution for 2.:**

This can be done by setting the CSS property's [`writing-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode) value to `vertical-lr` for the element `<div class="sidebar">`.

**CSS**

```
.sidebar {
    display: flex;
    writing-mode: vertical-lr;
    position: fixed;
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
    color: var(--alt3);
}
```